# Running APEX methods in Visualforce, is this possible?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the capabilities of the `Visualforce APIs` and the use of [functions in VisualForce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) but I'd like to do something like this:

Looking at the `Rendered` tag:

```
<apex:page ...>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!$Utils.checkChatterEnabled}">
        <apex:outputLabel for="enableChatterFeedTracking" value="Enable Chatter Feed Tracking" />
        <apex:outputText value="Chatter Enabled" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:page>
```

And than I have a class with `public` or `global` visibility, that **is NOT my controller or controller-extension**:

```
global class Utils{
  global static Boolean checkChatterEnabled(){
    sObject feedEnabled = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Meeting__Feed LIMIT 1');
    if(feedEnabled != null){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

***Obviously this doesn't compile with a failure message:***

> Save error: Field $Utils.checkChatterEnabled does not exist

Is this possible? *If **so** what am I doing wrong?* If not, is their an "Idea" or "Success" article about it ...?

Thanks

Updated - to make checkChatterEnabled static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To gain access to the functions for use in the rendered attribute (or anywhere else, for that matter), you would want to use an extension.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="pageController,Util">
    <!-- code here -->
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!Util.chatterFeedEnabled}">
        <!-- code -->
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:page>
```

Your class can then be written to accept a StandardController:

```
public class Util {
    public Util(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { }
    public Boolean getChatterFeedEnabled() {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can then use this extension on multiple pages as you see fit. Note that Components are a different beast, however. If you use a component with a controller, there must also be a constructor accepting that controller as a parameter:

```
public Util(MyComponentController controller) { }
```

You can have as many constructors as you see fit (we have a multi-purpose class with eight constructors for various components).

Comment: I realize this, but *I don't want to use the standard controller extension* and would prefer to access the methods in the `UTIL class` statically to avoid code-duplication. I guess I should have specified that UTIL is a _static class_.

Comment: That's the point of extensions, to avoid code duplication. Your class will only be defined once, and doesn't have to be pulled in to the page's controller. Unfortunately, anything that's not a controller or extension can't be accessed by the Visualforce runtime in an expression like that.